# Calibre - keep personal folder format

Tags: epub, pdf, calibre, formatting

I have spent the last few days manually organizing my ebook collection into folders and sub-folders. When I load everything into Calibre, everything gets changed from the title to the way its saved in my Library.

Is there a way where I can force Calibre to use MY titles and MY folders when creating a mass conversion? I want everything the way I have it, just converted to one format.

```
Main Folder
- First Category
---- Book 1
---- Book 2
---- Book n
---- Sub Category
------- Book 1
------- Book 2
- Second Category
---- Book 1
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Calibre doesn't look at the directory structure nor at the name of a file to determine the name of a book it imports. It tries to extract that information from the metadata that if finds **in** the file. What it actually retrieves depends on the file format.

I add all most all my books to Calibre using the command-line tool `calibredb`, specifically using Python program that gathers the correct info, corrects it where necessary, and then calls:

```
calibredb add --duplicates --authors="author names" --title="title of the book" file_name_of_the.ebook
```

If you provide the parameters, Calibre will no longer try to extract them from the ebook.

(There are a lot more options there use `calibredb add --help` to see them).

With a small program you should be able to walk the directory tree and automatically construct the right parameters for `calibredb`, or maybe an editor with learning mode working over the list of files should get you the script/batch file to do the upload into Calibre.